# Jquery disable old function and execute new function on select box change

Tags: jquery

I have two functions

first

```
function normal_validate() {
    $("#add_expense").validate({
        rules : {
            expense : {
                required : true
            },
            category : {
                required : true
            }
        },
        submitHandler : function(form) {
            $.post('add/add_expense_result.php', $("#add_expense").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#add_expense .message_outer').fadeIn('slow').html(data).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
            $('#add_expense')[0].reset();
            var first_category = $('#categories option:nth-child(1)').text();
            $('#add_expense .customSelectInner').html(first_category);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

second

```
function advanced_validate() {
    $("#add_expense").validate({
        rules : {
            expense : {
                required : true
            },
            category : {
                required : true
            },
            customer_name : {
                required : true,
                minlength : 3
            },
            customer_email : {
                email : true
            },
            customer_address : {
                required : true,
                minlength : 5
            }
        },
        submitHandler : function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('add/add_expense_result.php', $("#add_expense").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#add_expense .message_outer').fadeIn('slow').html(data).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
            $('#add_expense')[0].reset();
            var first_category = $('#categories option:nth-child(1)').text();
            $('#add_expense .customSelectInner').html(first_category);
            var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";
            var string_length = 5;
            var result = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
                var randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
                result += chars.substr(randomPos, 1);
            }
            $('input.customerCode').val(result);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.existingcustomer').autocomplete({
        source : 'suggest/suggest_customer.php',
        select : function(event, ui) {
            $('.customerId').val(ui.item.id);
            $('.customerCode').val(ui.item.code);
            $('.customerName').val(ui.item.name);
            $('.customerEmail').val(ui.item.email);
            $('.customerPhone').val(ui.item.phone);
            $('.customerAddress').val(ui.item.address);
            return false;
        },
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.name + " - " + item.address + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    };
    $(".existingCustomer").live("click", function() {
        $('input.customerName').removeClass('newcustomer');
        $('input.customerName').addClass('existingcustomer');
        $('input.customerCode').removeClass('newId');
        $('input.customerCode').addClass('oldId');
        $('.newCustomer').attr('checked', false);
        $('#customer_details input').val('');
        $('#customer_details textarea').val('');
        $(".existingcustomer").autocomplete("enable");
    })
    $(".newCustomer").live("click", function() {
        $('input.customerName').removeClass('existingcustomer');
        $('input.customerName').addClass('newcustomer');
        $('input.customerCode').removeClass('oldId');
        $('input.customerCode').addClass('newId');
        $('.existingCustomer').attr('checked', false);
        $('#customer_details input').val('');
        $('#customer_details textarea').val('');
        $('input.newId').val(result);
        $(".newcustomer").autocomplete("disable");
    });
}
```

i want normal_validate function on document ready. after my select box change , i want change function.

html

```
<form action="" method="post" id="add_expense">
    <section class="widget mb20 border">
        <h4 class="title">Expense Details <span class="info">(*) fields are mandatory</span></h4>
        <div class="inner_content">
            <div class="left">
                <p>
                    <label>Expense * (<?php echo $currency; ?>)</label>
                    <input type="text" name="expense" class="text" />
                    <br class="clear" />
                </p>
                <p class="category">
                    <label>Category</label>
                    <span class="select">
                        <select name="category" id="categories">
                            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                            <?php
                            if ($expense_categories !== FALSE && mysql_num_rows($expense_categories) > 0) {
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($expense_categories)) {
                                    $category = $row['category_name'];  ?>
                                    <option><?php echo $category; ?></option>
                                <?php }
                                    } 
                            ?>  
                        </select>
                        <span class="add_category"> new</span>
                    </span>                                 
                    <br class="clear" />
                </p>                        
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="mbn">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea name="description"  cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    <br class="clear" />
                </p>
                <input class="created_by text hidden" type="text" readonly name="created_by" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>"/>  
            </div>
            <br class="clear" />
        </div>  
    </section><!--(main content content_inner widget(create_invoice))-->
    <section class="widget col2  left  border mb20 hidden" id="customer_details">
        <h4 class="title">Customer Details</h4>
        <div id="customer_type">
            <span class="exist">
                <input type="checkbox" name="existing_customer" class="existingCustomer" checked="true"/>
                <label >Existing Customer</label> </span>
            <span class="new">
                <input type="checkbox" name="new_customer" class="newCustomer"/>
                <label >New Customer</label> </span>
        </div>
        <div class="inner_content">
            <p>
                <label>Name *</label>
                <input type="text" name="customer_name" class="customerName existingcustomer text"/>
                <br class="clear" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Address *</label>
                <textarea name="customer_address"  cols="30" rows="10" class="customerAddress"></textarea>          
                <br class="clear" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input type="text" name="customer_phone" class="customerPhone number"/>
                <br class="clear" />
            </p>
            <p class="hidden">
                <input type="text" name="customer_id" readonly class="customerId text " />
                <input class="customerCode" type='text'  name='customer_code' value=""/>
                <br class="clear" />
            </p>
            <p  class="mbn">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="customer_email" class="customerEmail text"/>
                <br class="clear" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </section><!--(widget orange customer_details_widget)-->
    <br class="clear" />
    <section class="submit_area">
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Ready to go!"/>
        <span class="message_outer"></span>
    </section>
</form>
```

jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        normal_validate();
        $('#categories').change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == 'repayment' || value == 'credit') {
                $('#customer_details').show();
                //i want  disable normal_validate function
                advanced_validate();
            } else {
                $('#customer_details').hide();
                //i want  disable advanced_validate function
                normal_validate();
            }

            if (value == 'repayment') {
                $('#customer_details .new').hide();
            } else {
                $('#customer_details .new').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

my problem is after select box value change to credit or repayment, still working normal_validate function.

Comment: Show the `<select>` HTML...

Comment: it is working see http://jsfiddle.net/UR6cD/

Comment: The code looks fine, you must be doing something that we can't see, or you've misunderstood what's being called.

Comment: now added whole function and html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
var value $("#categories option:selected").text();
```

instead of:

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

Taken from [jquery change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `option` value in your html `select`

```
<option value="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></option>
```

or
    change js script : 
    `var value = $("#categories option:selected").text();`

Please try this.

Comment: please see this part my jquery if (value == 'repayment') {
                $('#customer_details .new').hide();
            } else {
                $('#customer_details .new').show();
            }

this function works well!
only probelm with normal_validate and advanced_validate function. that function not changing. if remove normal_validate() function on document ready . now change function works..

Comment: @SAFEERN Just write two different functions with alert text. then choose value from select box and check alert is coming or not!

Comment: no luck. $('#customer_details .new').hide(); or show function works. so change function working properly. but if normal_validate function running , advanced_validate function not working.